# TSQL Query performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have the following query which takes about 20s to complete.

```
declare @shoppingBasketID int

select @shoppingBasketID = [uid]
from shoppingBasket sb
where sb.requestID = 21918154   and sb.[status] > 0

select
    ingredientGroup.shoppingBasketItemID as itemID,
    ingredientGroup.[uid] as groupUID
from shoppingBasketItem item
    left outer join shoppingBasketItemBundle itemBundle on itemBundle.primeMenuItemID = item.[uid]
    left outer join shoppingBasketItem bundleItem on bundleItem.[uid] = isnull(itemBundle.linkMenuItemID, item.[uid])
    left outer join shoppingBasketItemIngredientGroup ingredientGroup on ingredientGroup.shoppingBasketItemID = isnull(itemBundle.linkMenuItemID, item.[uid])
    left outer join shoppingBasketItemIngredient ingredient on ingredient.shoppingBasketItemIngredientGroupID = ingredientGroup.[uid]
where item.shoppingBasketID = @shoppingBasketID
```

The 'shoppingBasketItemIngredient' table has 40 millions rows.
When I change the last line to the following the query returns the results almost instantly. (I moved the first select into the second select query).

```
where item.shoppingBasketID = (select [uid] from shoppingBasket sb  where sb.requestID = 21918154       and sb.[status] > 0)
```

Do you know why?

Comment: I would assume that the query plan for the first version was cached with some incorrectness.  The parameterized version should be faster than the subquery version.

Comment: So you think the first version was slow because cached incorrectly? How is that possible? The code from above is taken from a stored procedure

Comment: What are the datatypes of `shoppingBasketItem.shoppingBasketId` and `shoppingBasket.uid`? I'm pondering that your use of an intermediate `INT` variable is forcing a conversion on every row. ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [query hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

When using a variable the query optimizer could generate a slow execution plan.
It's easier for a query optimizer to calculate the optimal plan when a fixed value is used.

But by adding the right hint(s) it could go for a faster execution plan.

For example:

```
select 
...
where item.shoppingBasketID = @shoppingBasketID
OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR (@shoppingBasketID UNKNOWN) );
```

In the example UNKNOWN was used, but you can give a value instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Adding "OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR (@shoppingBasketID UNKNOWN) )" doesn't work but if I replace UNKNOWN by an integer value (any value) the query executes fast. Looks like the query needs to be optimize with a query hint because each table I use to join is huge

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

Queries in stored procedures are compiled the first time they are run and the query plan is cached.  So, if you test the stored procedure on an empty table, then it might generate a bad query plan -- and that doesn't get updated automatically.

You can force a recompile at either the stored procedure or query level, using the option `WITH (RECOMPILE)`.  [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx) is some documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read the documentation and it is mentioned that "There are times when procedure recompilation must be forced and other times when it occurs automatically. Automatic recompiling occurs whenever SQL Server is restarted". SQL Server was restarted recently so I'm almost certain the problem doesn't come from that.